# Recursive functions.

Tags: functions, derivatives, recursion

If you have a recursive function 
$$g(x) = f(f(x))$$ and you know that $$f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 1, f''(0) = 2$$
Will then $$g(0) = 0, g'(0) = 1, g''(0) = 2$$
?

Comment: This isn't really a recursive definition because neither $f$ nor $g$ is defined in terms of itself. We can compute the derivatives of $g$ and evaluate at 0: $g'(0) = f'(f(0))f'(0)$; $g''(0) = f''(f(0))f'(0)^2 + f'(f(0))f''(0)$.

Comment: I get $g''(0)=4$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the chain rule we can arrive at the fact that $$g'(x)=(f(f(x)))'=f'(f(x))f'(x)$$ Then using the product rule you can find the second derivative. Can you take it from here?